# How can I determine which Private PPAs are slowing down updates?

Tags: apt, ppa

I've several PPA installed on my system. Every time I perform an `apt-get update` there's a moment in which the updating process remains stuck in this position (it lasts almost a minute):

```
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-it
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
100% [In lavorazione]
```

(I don't know in English how the last line is, something like "100% [Working]")

I presume this happens because a download of a PPA is slow. (Do you think this might be the reason?)

If so, I'd like to remove this PPA from my system.
The problem is that during this phase I can't distinguish among PPAs because all of them show this URL: `https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main`.
Is there a way to identify the PPA which is being updated in that particular moment?

Comment: Do you really need `apt-get update` to finish in one minute? On my system it takes about 3-4 minutes, because my internet connection is slow, and I fail to see that it could be disturbing.

Comment: I wondered whether there was a way to speed-up the process. If you say that is the physiological time, for me it's ok, it's not disturbing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true -o Acquire::Queue-Mode=access update`. This enables debugging options to make all HTTP requests sequential and show you every HTTP request going out and response coming back in.

Answer (score 0):

You might comment the referred PPA entry on /etc/apt/sources.list
Then do the update again and see if it keeps getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I can't identify the ppa since all of them show the same line while updating: `https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main`.